# Spark Structured Streaming metrics UI dashboard

Tags: apache-spark, graphite, spark-structured-streaming

I have used Spark Metrics Sinks, including csvSink, GraphiteSink, and GangliaSink etc, but only see three metric values related to Structured Streaming, such as inputRate, latency, ProcessingRate.

Is there any method I can implement to send the metrics, like queryProgress metrics to the metric sinks?

```scala
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
  override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query started: " + queryStarted.id)
  }
  override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query terminated: " + queryTerminated.id)
  }
  override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
    println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress)
  }
})
```

Also, I am running the app on Yarn Cluster mode, is there any good way to "pull" the metrics from the driver program?